# Angular execution issue in Eclipse Neon

Tags: angular

I am getting the below error:

ng init
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

in eclipse neon. I tried to create a new Angular project. However if i run the same command in cmd, it works fine.

Also, i have to set path in eclipse every time using Terminal to enable ng.

Comment: Please install 1.2.0 Angular2 Eclipse which should fix this problem.